# python scraping a response table from a selected option in dropdown list

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, html-table, web-crawler

i'm trying to scrape the pollutant concentration table from
the thing is, the values on the table changes based on the time selected on the dropdown list (it provides a 24 hours data from timestamp). I can only scrape the table based on the timestamp but I want to take all of the 24 hrs data and convert it to CSV file.

Comment: what have you tried so far? please edit your code in

Comment: I was told using select might work but I don't know how

Comment: can u add ur current output, and what u want it to be like instead?

Comment: I have used the select command and now I can take the table based on the index option. I wanted it to be able to take all of the data based on the hours and convert it to separate csv file for each hour. For now, I am able to convert a table of my choosing into csv

Comment: I also want to put it into a dataframe